# Twilio message sending not working in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

I'm trying to send sms from Twilio in ASP .NET but it throws this:

> The From phone number +XXXXXX is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound
>   phone number or short code for your account

My code looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("sms")]
public HttpResponseMessage SendMessage()
{
    var AccountSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    var AccountToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    TwilioClient.Init(AccountSid, AccountToken);
    var to = new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXX");
    var from = new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXX");
    var message = MessageResource.Create(to: to, from: from, body: "Hi from me");
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,message.Sid);

}
```

My error looks like this:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The From phone number +XXXXXX is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.",
  "ExceptionType": "Twilio.Exceptions.ApiException",
}
```

Comment: Change `var from = new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXX");` to `var from = new PhoneNumber("+YYYYYYYYYY");` where `+YYYYYYYYYY` is a number you purchased from Twilio.

Comment: @AlexBaban i have used the trial number from twilio. Does the trial number does't work ? I am confused...

Comment: There seems to be some problem in Twilio account configuration. Make sure you followed all steps on [tutorial]() and enabled permissions for your country code ]

Comment: While in trial mode, you can only send messages to non-Twilio phone numbers you've verified with Twilio. https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-to-use-your-free-trial-account

Comment: @AlexBaban i have used trial number of usa in "from" and in "to" i have used the  verified number . The "to" number is showing in my twilio verified number console.

Comment: @AlexBaban I was using test credentials from twilio that is why that error was throwing but when i used live credentials, the error has gone and message has been successfully sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using test credentials from twilio that is why that error was throwing but when i used live credentials, the error has gone and message has been successfully sent.

Comment: You could make your question more clear and put in the question body this information, about what kind of account you have and what kind of credentials you have used. It's not clear in the question what you were doing.

Comment: @AlexBaban yes that was my fault.I was not aware about the live and test credentials. Sorry for that. And thank you very much for your valuable answers. I really appreciate it .

Comment: So you're able to send text from your trial account. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlexBaban yes i am able to text from my trial account with my live credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As per Twilio, trial accounts are not able to send messages. they are simply there to test that you are making your API requests properly. Also, as per [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/test-credentials),  you can only workt with specific numbers and with few endpoints.